# framework implementation by handling version swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

In brief describing, I need to implement a framework which it supports versioning!

For example, I want to provide galley which its functions are changing by version; When it was V1.0, It was only showing images by next and previous buttons; but at V1.1, the auto sliding images;

Because I am using this gallery at two projects and one of them does not need to use sliding; How can I implement my framework which When I able to set version somewhere and the other features go to be hide!

**Note**: I know the pod versioning could help me; but really I want to have one package and use its features by some data which I pass it to

Comment: Isn't this precisely what bundles are for? Make two versions, 1.0 and 1.1, in a bundle. Then load the one you want. But honestly, isn't an optional input in the method a better solutions?

Comment: Sending version as a parameter at end method is not my purpose, but if I could config my framework by version then use it, It is nice solution, could I do ?